# variable parent tag Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I want to be able to put my content inside a different tag according to a condition.

For example, my content should be wrapped inside a `<table>` or `<div>` according to a condition.

```
<table|div class="someClass" [ngClass]="{'another-class': condition}">
    My content here with all the styling 
</table|div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular *ngIf and a [template outlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet#description) if you don't want to duplicate the inner html.

```html
<table *ngIf="isTable" class="someClass" [class.another-class]="condition">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate"></ng-container>
</table>
<div *ngIf="!isTable" class="someClass" [class.another-class]="condition">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #myTemplate>
  My content here with all the styling
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I just wanted it to be more flexible than this
But your solution is very Ok